# How to search a file in linux containing a particular string and then printing all contents of that file?

Tags: linux, grep, cat

Requirement : Searching a file in linux containing a string and then printing all contents of that file.

Approach I used: **grep -ri "<string_name>" | cut -d : -f1**
Using this command I was able to determine the filename. But I want to display all content of the file. What should we add in the above command so that entire file content is visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file name directly from grep, without having to manipulate its output by using the `--files-with-matches` option, or its short hand `-l`.

Your command would look like:

`grep -l "<string_name>"`

Which you can then use with other tools, ie:

`cat $(grep -l "SEARCH_PATTERN" [FILE...])`

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you can pipe the extracted filename to cat to display the file's contents:

`grep "string-to-search" /path/to/directory/* | cut -d: -f1 | uniq | xargs cat`

This command will search for the string "string-to-search" in all files in the /path/to/directory/ directory and print the contents of the files that contain the string.

The cut command is used to extract the filename from the output of grep, and the uniq command removes duplicate filenames. The xargs command is used to pass the list of filenames to the cat command, which prints the contents of each file.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && /regexp/{ ARGV[ARGC++]=FILENAME; nextfile } NR>FNR' file
```

For example:

```
$ seq 5 > file

$ awk 'NR==FNR && /3/{ ARGV[ARGC++]=FILENAME; nextfile } NR>FNR' file
1
2
3
4
5

$ awk 'NR==FNR && /7/{ ARGV[ARGC++]=FILENAME; nextfile } NR>FNR' file
$
```

If your version of awk doesn't support `nextfile` (many do these days) it'll just run a little slower than if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` to search for files matching REGEXP

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q REGEXP {} \; -exec  cat {} \;
```